# 7zip takes forever to extract

Tags: jenkins, 7zip

Compressing a set of folders using 7zip, like this:

```
 def list = ["dir1", "dir2", "dir3"]
                   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                     def dir = list.get(i);
                       bat "7z a %cd%\\artifacts\\${dir}.zip %cd%\\src\\${dir}\\obj\\*"
                       }
```

Then copy over the zips to a shared drive and extract them remotely using:

```
def list_a = ["dir1", "dir2", "dir3"]
                for (int i = 0; i < list_a.size(); i++) {
                def dir = list_a.get(i);
                    bat "copy %cd%\\artifacts\\${dir}.zip  \\\\shared_drive\"
                    bat "7z x \\\\shared_drive\\\${dir}.zip -o\\\\shared_drive\\\${dir} -y"   //This step with extraction, takes a very long time for folders with a lot of files in it ( as compared using the GUI (right click and extract on the folder)
                    bat "del /Q \\\\shared_drive\\\${dir}.zip"
                }
```

I am retaining the folder structure while extracting.

Is there a way in which i can fasten the extraction process to the speed that i get while using the graphical interface with the mouse?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/131899/how-to-make-7-zip-faster Look at fredricks answer

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect a difference between CLI and GUI. There's one common pitfall in your setup, though: **extracting an archive from network to the same network drive can be very slow**.

It will be better to completely avoid the intermediate step of copying the archive to the share. If `%cd%` is a local drive in your setup, then this will do:

```
def list_a = ["dir1", "dir2", "dir3"]
                for (int i = 0; i < list_a.size(); i++) {
                def dir = list_a.get(i);
                    bat "7z x %cd%\\artifacts\\${dir}.zip -o\\\\shared_drive\\\${dir} -y"   //This step with extraction, takes a very long time for folders with a lot of files in it ( as compared using the GUI (right click and extract on the folder)
                }
```

Otherwise, it may be worth copying the archive to a local drive first, and extract it then.